# How to get NSPid on kernel 3.10

Tags: process, proc

In kernel 4.1 and above, `/proc/[pid]/status` contains these 4 lines:

```
NStgid: 1
NSpid:  1
NSpgid: 1
NSsid:  1
```

This allow a process in parent namespace to know about that process' PID in all namespaces. But those lines are only added in kernel 4.1, so kernel 3.10 doesn't have them.

So, given a process PID, how to get that process PID in all namespaces, or at least the PID in the deepest namespace that process belong to in kernel 3.10? Upgrade kernel is not possible since it's a production server, so a change that big is very hard.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

See `/proc/[pid]/sched`:

```bash
$ cat /proc/8416/sched
bash (918, #threads: 1)
-------------------------------------------------------------------
se.exec_start                                :    2664031641.263979
se.vruntime                                  :       2781932.438772
se.sum_exec_runtime                          :             5.544571
se.nr_migrations                             :                    5
```

`8416` is the pid in namespace, and `918` is the host pid.

So given a host pid `918`, `nsenter` it's namespace and list all processes:

```bash
nsenter --target 918 --mount --uts --ipc --net --pid ps
PID   USER     TIME  COMMAND
 8416 java-app  0:00 /bin/bash
 8606 root      0:00 -bash
15416 root      0:00 -bash
```

Check `/proc/8416,8606,15416/sched` to see which one matches host pid `918`, and that one is the answer.

Above inspired by jattach this [issue](https://github.com/apangin/jattach/issues/13) and this [commit](https://github.com/apangin/jattach/commit/e408839a7b2f90b31cba8810012a9261c910b968).